# Dynamic change of class of <TR> with Jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my first post, and first please forgive me for my poor english.

I have a problem I really can't fix:

I have a `<table>` of questions,

1. the first question is visible (class:visible), the others are hidden (class:hidden)

   ```
           $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.hidden').hide();
   ```
2. When people click on the first question, I want the second question to appear (and the first question to turn to grey, using a 'done' class).

> ```
> $('.visible:not(.done)').click(function(){ 
>                 $(this).addClass('done'); 
>                 $('.hidden:first').toggle(500).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
>             })
> ```

The first question is now done (class:done) and the 2nd question should be the only one to react to a click(), and so on... But it doesn't work: the other `<tr>`  appear only when I click on the 1st `<tr>`.

Can someone give me a hand on this problem ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the classes dynamically and your click event handler is a class selector based you will have to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event.

```
$('.visible:not(.done)').live("click", function(){ 
    $(this).addClass('done'); 
    $('.hidden:first').toggle(500).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/eqeta3)**